Can an HRV/ERV successfully let a house get cooler?
I know ERVs/HRVs are designed to circulate air while minimizing energy exchange but I'm wondering if I can use my ERV to let my home get cooler if it is cooler outside the home. Imagine I have a house that is 3000 sqft. Let's say my house is at 25c and I'd like it to be cooler and it is 20c outdoors. My ERV can operate at 200CFM.  I don't know what the numbers mean, but at higher CFMs looks like my unit has 50% efficiency. I know I could open windows but that is not always possible due to bugs and weather or for safety.
How effectively could running my ERV at this maximum 200cfm let my home cool down when the outside is cooler?
If we flip things around, could it also let a house get warmer if it is warmer outside?

@Harper-ReinstateMonica of course that is it's intended purpose, but given that it is not 100% efficient and also brings in cooler air, would it not cool the home? AC is expensive, while running an ERV costs nearly nothing.

@Harper-ReinstateMonica Windows can't always be used. Some windows don't operate, there are noises, bugs, safety concerns, weather phenomena, smells, polutants, etc. Also, the ERV has the added benefit of bringing in fresh air and can be used in a smart way and I don't have a way to use my windows with smart technology. Yes I know this is not the intended purpose of the ERV, which is made clear in the opening sentence of my question.

FWIW I wish there was an ERV with a thermostat and bypass function that would turn the ERV into a simple air exchanger depending on whether the outside air temp would get the inside air temp closer to the thermostat setpoint. There would be no question in this scenario that using such a device would be an obvious and easy win.

The wording of this question implied that the HRV/ERV could actively cool/warm a house. Changed to show the HRV/ERV will allow temperature change but not force it.

@Triplefault I don't understand and don't agree with the edits. What do you mean "let" the home cool down if the ERV is the device actively bringing in cool air from outside?? Doesn't "letting" suggest that this would happen somehow passively? The ERV would be doing the work here.

@statueuphemism Yes I would love for my ERV to bypass the entire energy core if I wanted it to. It does have a sensor that changes how it functions based on the outside temp and it is called a "smart" setting, but unfortunately it cannot bypass the core.

Fans don't "cool". They move air around. HRV/ERV's are only dual fans with a little scientific jiggery-pokery in the middle to allow heat transfer between the airflows. As written, your question asked, "Can my HRV/ERV cool my house". The answer to that is No, they can only allow cool air from outside to transfer into the house slower than a regular fan could. HRV/ERV's don't "actively cool". They actually add heat, from the power used by the fans. Only an AC or heat pump can "cool" the house.

FWIW you can edit your question to roll back my edits. But as it was written before it showed unintentional but easily-misleading wording.

@Triplefault By that argument a whole house fan running at 1000CFM in the dead of winter does not actively cool a house... That doesn't make sense to me. I hear where you're coming from but I don't agree.

"a whole house fan running at 1000CFM in the dead of winter does not actively cool a house" That is correct. It's not the fan that cools. It's the cool air getting sucked in that cools. All the fan/HRV/ERV does is move the air around.

As mentioned above, you may roll back the edit. I'm flagging two of your comments for personal attacks, your last and the one above where you told a well-respected member of this community to face-palm themself. You're violating the CoC.

@Triplefault I only said that because they said /facepalm to me! And I don't see an attack, I just said you were being silly.

Some better alternatives to consider:
Heat Recovery Ventilators and Energy Recover Ventilators are intended to minimize the change of internal temperature (and moisture for ERVs) while introducing fresh air into your home. This sounds like the opposite of what you are trying to achieve.
If you are just looking to make the inside of your home closer to the temperature of the outside air, you might want to open the windows and add screens/awnings or look at a whole house fan with a filter if you need to reduce allergens or have other concerns with open windows.
There is no one-size-fits-all answer to this question:
It is impossible to come up with a one-size-fits-all answer as it depends entirely on the initial conditions (inside temp vs outside temp), latent heat/cooling factors (e.g. home location, building insulation envelope, and how much heat is built up inside the home such as an attic on a sunny day well after the sun has gone down), and what your definition of “effective” is since time to cool down to a comfortable temperature would be included in many people’s definitions of effectiveness.
The best way to know if you already have this setup installed is to try it and see if it’s effective enough for what you want.
Going through the specific example in the question:
To throw some best case numbers at your example conditions: If you assume a standard 8 ft ceiling in your 3,000 sqft home, that gives you roughly 24,000 cubic feet of air to exchange. CFM is an air flow rate which stands for cubic feet per minute. At 200 CFM, the fastest you could possibly exchange all 24,000 cubic feet of air is 120 minutes (2 hours). Since you have an ERV, I’ll make the assumption that you have an excellent insulation envelope to prevent heat/cold from creeping in from the roof and walls and call it 100% effective insulation to give the best chance of success.
In this best case example, you will eventually cool your home if it is attached to a central HVAC and the HVAC fan is used to help move the exchanged air (some solutions push and pull air to a single room, so the effective air exchange with the entire home is reduced in those setups), but it’d be on the order of multiple hours when you factor in only 50% temperature exchange on each air exchange.
The air temperature inside the home is an exponential decay function where the inside temperature never fully reaches the outside temperature and slows down how fast it changes temperature the closer the inside temperature gets to the outside temperature. Best case with your 25 C inside and 20 C outside example is a 2.5 C reduction over the first 2 hours and then halve the reduction for every complete air exchange after that: another 1.25 C over the next two hours, 0.625 C over the next two hours, etc). This is simplified math to show absolute best case where the real world scenario would be slower since cooled air is going to mix and be purged again before 2 hours which further slows the cooling effect.
However, if you factor in real world conditions such as latent heat from an attic at the end of a sunny day, then the speed of cooling needs to be able to overcome that heat rise where time very much is a factor. If you have AC in your home and it was sized correctly (e.g. according to a Manual J load calculation or equivalent), the cooling energy capacity of your AC unit can give an indicator of how much heat is expected to leak into your home on a reasonably hot summer day. That said, 25 C isn’t a particularly hot day at all. However, was it a really hot summer day that cooled off quickly to 25 C in your example? If so, you’d still need to get pretty close to matching the performance of your AC to remove heat using your ERV and not have the temperature rise due to the latent heat in the attic. Otherwise, if it’s a cloudy spring day where 25 C is the highest temperature of the day, it has a better shot at cooling your home since there is less latent heat to overcome.
TLDR
Is it an efficient way to make the air more similar to the outside air temperature? Not particularly. Is it effective? Again, that’s a subjective assessment.

The problem is trying to assess if it's effective. The internal temperature of a house depends on the outdoor temperature, solar heat gain, if the AC is running etc. It's too difficult to determine whether this works over other factors. I was hoping some math might figure it out!

What other info do you need? We have the official efficiency rating for the unit, the CFM, the temperature delta, and the size of the house. If you need the specific terminology for the efficiency I can get that. Heck here is the spec sheet. https://broan-nutone.com/getmedia/65812a9e-d4e1-448d-8495-f3c1b915d608/Spec_Sheet_X30ERVE_en.pdf And it doesn't matter how long it takes to drop 2c if it takes less energy than the air conditioner.

@Behacad What size is your AC unit and how much energy does it consume to operate (Watts)? This is necessary information for an energy usage comparison. A Manual J load calculation would be ideal, but for the sake of simplicity we could assume the unit was sized correctly according to something like a Manual J load calculation and the building envelope has not changed significantly since installation.

I'm not looking to figure out the AC side of the equation here, just how well the ERV cools things and if it's even on the scale of noticeable.

@Behacad Not all 3,000 sqft homes are the same (e.g. one with a good thermal envelope in an Alaskan summer vs poorly insulated in Texas). The size/cooling capacity of an AC unit (e.g. 24,000 BTU/hr), if sized properly, indicates what the usual expected heat load during summer is in your climate and estimates how much heat is expected to be introduced on a hot day. The air temp over time due to cooling from an ERV is an exponential decay function that needs to overcome latent heat factors such as a warmed roof/attic that is leaking heat into the living space after the sun has gone down.

Is the juice...
Since you're mostly using American units, I'll follow in-kind. The isobaric specific heat of air is 0.24 BTU per pound per degree F.
1 pound of air is 13.33 cubic feet. 3 pounds of air is 40 cubic feet. 15 pounds of air is 200 cubic feet and we're at your CFM rate.  15 pounds per minute, 900 pounds per hour.
You claim 5 degree C difference in temperature or 9 degree F.
You claim the ERV is 50% efficient. (with humidity factored in? Big "if".). Anyway that implies our air moving through that thing will change 4.5 degrees F.
So I'm getting 0.24 BTU/lb/degF x 4.5 degF x 900 lb/hr.
Do the math, cancel the units, I get 972 BTU/hr of nominal heating or cooling given those parameters.  We're still disregarding humidity and it's extremely high impact on both temperature and practical comfort i.e. perception of temperature.
... worth the squeeze?
The ERV has a variable fan speed, with watts NOT linear to CFM (not a surprise). At peak 200 CFM I estimate 100 watts of power.
But there's a problem. That 100 watts of power all turned into heat, and it wound up in the house. 100 watts for 1 hour = 341 BTU, so that's a demerit, knocking us down to 972-341 = 631 BTUs in that hour. So bringing in 631 BTUs cost us 100 watts, or 6.31 BTUs/watt ~= SEER.  Or another way of looking at it is 631 BTUs / 341 BTUs = a COP of 1.85.
"But wait. I don't agree with the demerit, what if the fan's heat is pushed outside?" Alrighty sure, let's try those numbers.  100 watts to move 972 BTU = SEER of 9.72.  And our COP rises to 972/341 = COP of 2.85.
Whatever, won't make much difference.
Is that good? Well, when the government even bothered to set a standard, they set 10 SEER - and that's literally That 70's Air Conditioner with its quaint R22 Freon. Since then it's been jacked up to 14 SEER.  Even the cruddiest Asian style split systems start at 18 SEER and go as high as 36 SEER.
And for COP (which works in both a heating and cooling context)? Technology Connections has a whole video on when you can expect to have less than 2.7 COP in the harshest Chicago winter.  TLDW: 106 hours that winter.
Of course efficiency is variable depending on conditions. Above is worst-case or EPA spec conditions, but your pre-condition is always a case where the heat pump is "pumping downhill", which means it will be running at much higher than spec efficiency.  Even That 70s A/C could roundly beat 10 SEER, and maybe even hit 25 SEER, in those conditions, where I would also expect 7++ COP from heat pumps.

This is very interesting. Note that the efficiency I believe already takes into account the electricity consumption, so perhaps that is not as relevant? And it would be 60W I think worse case. It is called Total Recovery Efficiency and adjusts for energy. If we get 972BTU per hour, isn't that decent? Isn't 972 BTU worth 284 watts if I used purely electric heating/cooling?

Note that this calculation is only good assuming perfect air exchange (only air at the initial temp of 77 F is expelled by the ERV) for the first air exchange over roughly the first two hours to accomplish a 4.5 F drop in the specific conditions raised in the question. On the second air exchange, the 4.5 F in the equation drops to 2.25 F if the internal temperature was brought down by 4.5 F, but still uses the same energy to operate the fans. This is an oversimplification, but with real world air mixing, the efficiency drops even further.
